# Why is preg_replace removing backslashes?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string which contains two backslashes:

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
```

If I echo it, I get what I expect:

```
echo $str; // some_string\\
```

But if I use that same string as a replacement in a `preg_replace` call, I get only one backslash:

```
echo preg_replace("//", $str, ""); // outputs some_string\
```

Is that behavior expected, and if so how can I make `preg_replace` output the same string as the input?

Comment: Am I missing something ... that `preg_replace()` contains only delimiters - there's  no content to the pattern?

Comment: That is just for the demo, i stripped it out.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function with the wrong parameter order:

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject)
```

> Searches `$subject` for matches to `$pattern` and replaces them with `$replacement`.

After changing the order of parameters the [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function returns the expected value:

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
echo $str; // some_string\\

echo preg_replace("/(\/\/)/", "", $str); // some_string\\
```

In case you want to replace the chars `//` your current regex pattern isn't valid. You need to use the pattern `/(\/\/)/` to replace the `//` chars with the replacement value (second parameter).

---

In case you want to replace between chars (and need to use the `$str` as replacement value) you need to quote the `$str` so the [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) doesn't convert the `\\\\` to `\\`. In this case you can use the following, using [`addslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php):

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
var_dump(preg_replace("//", addslashes($str), "hi")); // string(41) "some_string\\hsome_string\\isome_string\\"
```

You can also use the [`addslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on the result of [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to get the same output:

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
var_dump(addslashes(preg_replace("//", $str, "hi"))); // string(41) "some_string\\hsome_string\\isome_string\\"
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/5aZ23G

Comment: I suppose it kinda depends on what the OP is trying to prove... technically the replacement they're using states replace *"nothing"* in an empty string with *'some_string\\\\'* - so, logically, you should see *'some_string\\'* ... maybe. You actually get that result with `preg_replace("//", preg_quote($str), "")`

Comment: That is not what i aksed for, i am using the parameters in the correct order. I want to use the double backslashed string as a replacement. I am using an empty subject just for the demo.

Comment: preg_quote breaks other cases:
echo preg_replace("//", preg_quote('some_string?'), ""); // some_string\?
preg_quote should be used only on regexes, not on replacements.

Comment: Same goes for backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
echo preg_replace("//", $str, "");
```

Technically that should replace the content of the empty string with `some_string\\\\` and echo it out - however, what's happening is that `preg_replace` *sees* the escaped `\` characters in the replacement so treats the expression like `preg_replace('//', 'some_string\\', '');`

When you echo that out, it acts like `echo 'some_string\\';` so what you see displayed is `some_string\`.

You can see the proof if you use <s>`preg_quote()`</s> `addslashes()` as that escapes the `\` characters first.

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';
echo preg_replace("//", addslashes($str), ""); # echos 'some_string\\'
```

This definitely seems a little "quirky" as it won't do this with a generic function:

```
$str = 'some_string\\\\';

function a($s) {
    var_dump($s);
    return $s;
}

echo a($str);
```

results in:

> string(13) "some_string\\"
>   some_string\\

... as you'd expect.

Comment: Wouldn't preg_replace treat the replacement string "as-it-is", and just put it there? Why isn't print() doing so?  Preg_quote is a not-go, since it will break the string if there are other special characters. preg_quote should be used only on the regex, not on the replacement or subject.

Comment: Good point about `preg_quote()` - I think it still *processes* the backslashes twice though; once with `preg_replace` and again with `echo` - `addslashes()` gives the same result as `preg_quote`.

Comment: ... or it could be in the way `preg_replace` *returns* `'some_string\\\\'` thinking about it ... might need to look at the source code for a definitive answer.

Comment: ... this definitely seems a bit "quirky" : `var_dump($str); // string(13) "some_string\\"` <- so that's what `preg_replace()` is working with.